# Compilation failure in cpu_features_get.cc

Tags: cobalt

I'm trying to compile Cobalt and getting errors building cpu_features_get.cc. The specific version I'm building is here: https://github.com/Metrological/cobalt/blob/master/src/starboard/shared/linux/cpu_features_get.cc and it appears to be based on Cobalt 22. I'm building using stbgcc-6.3.18, only Ubuntu 20.04. Sysroot is set to the cross compiler. And I'm building the starboard port at https://github.com/Metrological/cobalt/tree/master/src/third_party/starboard/wpe/brcm/arm, for ARM64.

An example of the error:

```
cpu_features_get.cc:381:12: error: 'HWCAP_SET_FOR_ARMV8' was not declared in this scope
```

There follow others, all related to HWCAP #defines.

As far as I can tell, the file defines these values if:

```
53: #if SB_IS(32_BIT) || defined(ANDROID)
```

Neither of these is true - I am compiling for ARM64 on Linux.

The code using HWCAP_SET_FOR_ARMV8 and the other missing defines is conditionally compiled as well:

```
340: #if SB_IS(ARCH_ARM) || SB_IS(ARCH_ARM64)
...
// Construct hwcap bitmask by the feature flags in /proc/cpuinfo
uint32_t ConstructHwcapFromCPUInfo(ProcCpuInfo* cpu_info,
                                   int16_t architecture_generation,
                                   uint32_t hwcap_type) {
  if (hwcap_type == AT_HWCAP && architecture_generation >= 8) {
    // This is a 32-bit ARM binary running on a 64-bit ARM64 kernel.
    // The 'Features' line only lists the optional features that the
    // device's CPU supports, compared to its reference architecture
    // which are of no use for this process.
    SB_LOG(INFO) << "Faking 32-bit ARM HWCaps on ARMv"
                 << architecture_generation;
    return HWCAP_SET_FOR_ARMV8;
  }
...
...
```

So ARCH_ARM64 is true, and this code is compiled. But the defines are missing because it's not 32-bit. This seems contradictory and to my eyes could never have worked. How is it possible to compile Cobalt for ARM64?

Comment: I've noticed that ConstructHwcapFromCPUInfo() is only called if SB_IS(32_BIT), so I've wrapped the definition of this function in that #if. It compiles fine now, but it would be good to know from a Cobalt dev if this is a bug I should report and/or contribute a patch for?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for a very delayed response - this looks like a possible bug in how the conditionals are set in Cobalt code. Note that the build is tested with a limited set of compilers / architectures, not all issues like these would be caught.

Please also check the latest guidance as to where to file the bugs on [cobalt.dev](https://cobalt.dev/communication.html), we currently recommend filing issues in our [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=181120).